# loading mongodb oplog.rs in to spark dataframe

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load oplog.rs from MongoDB into a spark DataFrame, it loads the metadata and i verified it through `printSchema` function, but when i try to execute an action like show or count it gives me out this error `scala.MatchError: ((BsonMinKey,null),0) (of class scala.Tuple2)`. i also tried registering it as a temptable, but still gives same error.

```
val customReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map(
  "uri" -> 
    "mongodb://username:password@host_name:port/local.oplog.rs?authSource=xxxxx"
))

val dataframe = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").
  options(customReadConfig.asOptions).load
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

The default Partitioner for versions of Mongo >= 3.2 is the `MongoSamplePartitioner`, it uses (like all the other partitioners) a `partitionKey` and when it creates the partitions it uses a `BsonMinKey` and `BsonMaxKey` to define the boundaries for each partition. The match error you are encountering is likely occurring here:

```
  def createPartitions(partitionKey: String, splitKeys: Seq[BsonValue], 
      locations: Seq[String] = Nil, addMinMax: Boolean = true): 
      Array[MongoPartition] = {
        val minKeyMaxKeys = (new BsonMinKey(), new BsonMaxKey())
        val minToMaxSplitKeys: Seq[BsonValue] = if (addMinMax) minKeyMaxKeys._1 +: splitKeys :+ minKeyMaxKeys._2 else splitKeys
        val minToMaxKeysToPartition = if (minToMaxSplitKeys.length == 1) minToMaxSplitKeys else minToMaxSplitKeys.tail
        val partitionPairs: Seq[(BsonValue, BsonValue)] = minToMaxSplitKeys zip minToMaxKeysToPartition
        partitionPairs.zipWithIndex.map({
           case ((min: BsonValue, max: BsonValue), i: Int) => MongoPartition(i, createBoundaryQuery(partitionKey, min, max), locations)
      }).toArray
}
```

What that error is telling you is that your `max` is being set to null, and as you can see in the code there is only one case that is handled. If you didn't set a `partitionKey` to use, the partitioner will use `_id` by default, you can read about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/configuration/#conf-mongosamplepartitioner)

The `oplog.rs` collection does not have an `_id` key by default, the unique id of the oplog record is the amazingly named `h`, it is a number. So, in order to have the partitioner do the right thing, you need to set in your `SparkConf` or `ReadConfig` the `spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.partitionKey` to `h`.

```
 new SparkConf()
   //all of your other settings
   .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.partitionKey", "h")
```